# .hgignore whole directory tree excepting one specific file

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Can anyone tell me the .hgignore pattern to track one specific file in a directory and to ignore everything else?

I have a "media" directory which contains a "default.png", for obvious purposes, and the rest of the directory will hold user media.  We want hg to ignore everything in the media directory excepting the default file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
syntax: regex
^media/.*
```

or (leave it in the default glob and do)

```
media/**
```

and then manually `hg add media/default.png`.

In mercurial (unlike in CVS) you can add files that match your ignore patterns and they work fine.  So ignore broadly and `hg add` what you want tracked.

Comment: this does work however it requires you to manually add the files you want and hg will not notice if you add a new file that matches the pattern (if you matched on *.c for example).

Comment: Entirely true.  I still prefer it to the negative-look-ahead stuff, but not everyone does.  Personally I just make sure my transitory files and my stuff-to-keep end up in different directories so I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

```
syntax: regex
^media/(?!default.png$)
```

almost the same as John Mee's but matches to the end of the line, instead of anything that starts with default.png.

if you wanted to allow any .c file but nothing else, you could use:

```
^media/(?!.+\.c$)
```

Answer (score 5):

Summing it up as a BKM (Best Known Method)

Either hgignore everything, and then hg add back the few files you want to track.

Or use a pattern such as

```
syntax: regex
^path/(?!files-that-you-want-not-to-ignore$)
```

(I just wanted to see the full answer in one place.)

Comment: How do I specify multiple files?

Answer (score 4):

Never mind this seems to work...

```
syntax: regex
^media/(?!default.png)
```

Comment: this would also match default.png.sadkjsdhfdshfjkds

Comment: yeah, needs a '$' on the end to be sure. see your answer.