# Mercurial ignore all files except specific file names

Tags: mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I have a large file system in which almost every folder has a file called content.txt

I want to track every file named content.txt and automatically ignore everything else. I want the repo to automatically track new files named content.txt so I don't want to ignore everything in the .hgignore and then manually add.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It has to be regexp mode, not glob
2. You must debug <strike>path-part of regexp</strike>, but "all except content.txt" draft is `re:.*\.(?!content.txt)` as hope

Alternative solution can be
* ignore all
* add content.txt files pattern to commit command (-I option), see `hg help commit` and `hg help patterns`

`hg commit -I '**content.txt'`

Edit

`re:.*/(?!content.txt)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work as expected.

Using your first solution ignores all files except three that do not have an extension in their name. All of the content.txt files are still ignored (and these are the files I want to track).

The second solution doesn't work either. When I enter `hg add -n -I '**content.txt'`, it executes the command but doesn't display any files. I would expect this to display all of the content.txt files here.

Comment: When I did the `hg add` above that was with all files ignored. I *can* do the `hg add -n -I '**content.txt'` and see all of the context.txt files to be added, but this won't automatically pick up new context.txt files.

Comment: @Xenocideae - path part of regexp must be fixed. "\." is wrong, definitely. `hg commit -I ` will (I suppose without testing) commit only **modified** content.txt, not modified files not appear in changeset by design (TBT!)

Comment: @Xenocideae - [my starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1678121/960558) of Regexp solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
syntax: regexp
\.(?!txt$)[^.]+$ # "*." is followed by "txt" and we're at the end
(?<!\.)txt$ # "txt" follows a "."
(?<!/)content\. # "content." follows path separator
(?<!content)\. # "." follows "content"
```

I left in the comments I made while experimenting, to make sense of it all. (That's glob syntax in the first one.)